# aliasSub Graphite function help in Grafana

Tags: regex, function, grafana, graphite

I am struggling with formatting some Graphite metrics using the [aliasSub](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub) function and regular expressions within a Grafana query.

The defined Series gives the metric a string of `icinga2.Customer_websites_(SIT).services.my_domain_co_uk.http.perfdata.time.value`

By trial and error, I have successfully edited this using the [aliasSub](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub) function to rename the metric to `my_domain_co_uk` using:

```
aliasSub(^(.*)\.Customer_websites_\(SIT\)\.services\.(.*)\.http.perfdata.time.value,\2)
```

How do I now use a nested aliasSub function and regular expressions to replace the `_` with `.` so that I end up with `my.domain.co.uk`?

Comment: `aliasSub(YOUR_CURRENT_QUERY, "-", ".")` ?